# Rails association group by count with eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models associated with each other:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :articles
end
```

I need to calculate the number of articles written by each author -- returning a hash like so:

```
{"John" => 6, "Peter" => 20, "Alice" => 12}
```

In order to avoid the N+1 queries problem, I tried this:

```
Article.includes(:author).group(:author_id).count

# => {1 => 6, 2 => 20, 3 => 12 }
```

This is sort of correct in the sense that John's id is 1, Peter's id is 2 and so on, but I need their names (column :name) in the hash instead of id.

How can I do this with the least number of queries hitting the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **joins** instead of **includes** as shown below.

```
Article.joins(:author).group("authors.name").count
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In the rails console, I get:

irb(main):008:0> Article.joins(:author).group("author.name").count
(2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, author.name AS author_name FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "articles"."author_id" GROUP BY author.name
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: author.name: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, author.name AS author_name FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "articles"."author_id" GROUP BY author.name
from (irb):8

Comment: Try this one   Article.joins(:author).group("authors.name").count.  I missed 's' in my previous answer

Comment: Adding the missing 's' worked beautifully. This is a great answer.